# Как найти шаблон в строке

Tags: python, re

**Мне нужно заменить все:**

```
<a href="t.me/url">text</a>
```

**на:**

```
[text](t.me/url)
```

Разумеется ссылка и текст меняются.
Думаю это можно сделать с помощью модуля **re**, но не понимаю синтаксиса.

Comment: Как вариант. re.sub(r'<a\shref="t\.me\/\w{0,}">\w{0,}<\/a>', '[text](t.me/url)', text)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод:

```
import re
str = '<a href="t.me/url">text</a>'
re.sub(r'<a\s+href\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+)</a>', r'[\2](\1)', str)
```

[Песочница](https://regex101.com/r/AJYPlp/1).